# Orchard - Database indexes

Tags: orchardcms

Does anyone know if there's a recommended set of database indexes for Orchard's core modules? I can't seem to find much info around this, and while I appreciate that the code uses NHibernate to abstract the underlying database, I suspect 99% of users will simply be using SQL server/Express as the default DB and would require suitable indexes to be added. For example on: `Orchard_Framework_ContentItemVersionRecord ([Published], [ContentItemRecord_id])`

If there isn't already, would it be a good idea for the core modules to have a recommended set of indexes documented somewhere, as they're clearly going to be required for any serious deployments based on an RDBMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that some indices would help queries. However with indices it really depends on the usage pattern so there are not many built-in; but you can always add them yourself depending on your specific usage (you can also use SQL Server's tools to recommend indices for your). You can even [add indices from migrations](http://english.orchardproject.hu/blog/modifying-another-orchard-module-s-db-schema-with-schemabuilder) to other modules' tables.

In the latest source of Orchard (not yet released) there are also some more default indicies, also for `ContentItemVersionRecord`. You can see them in `FrameworkDataMigration` in the 1.x branch.